# Typefaces Look Off/Different After an Upgrade?

Tags: fonts, pandoc, mactex, printing

I used pandoc to convert my markdown files into PDFs.  The command I use to do this is as follows

```
pandoc myfile.md -s -o myfile.pdf
```

and then I convert that PDF to a half size layout via

```
pdflatex booklet.tex
```

where `booklet.tex` looks like this

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}
\includepdf[pages=-,booklet,turn=false,landscape]{myfile.pdf}
\end{document}%
```

I understand how this works at high level (pandoc makes a LaTeX file from my markdown file and feeds it to `pdflatex`, and then the second command transforms the generated PDF) -- but I'm far from a power user of either system.

Recently, I did a big systems update where I upgraded the version of `pandoc` on my system, reinstalled MacTeX, and used the *TeX Live Utility* to update all my packages.  After doing all this, the typeface/fonts in my documents look off.

By "off" I mean they're printing with a darker weight, and the kerning is slightly tighter. Here's an image that demonstrates what I mean.

[image: image of side by side text showing weight and kerning differences]

I'm at a loss where to even begin debugging this.  My first guess is a default font (or perhaps sizing/kerning/weight) changed but I don't know if that would be in pandoc, or in pandoc's template, or something in the cavalcade of binaries that make up the MacTex distribution.  I don't (yet) know much about how fonts work in LaTeX -- I've always just let it spit out the default.

So, two questions:

- Does anyone know what might have changed here? Like is this a known thing that happens to LaTeX systems sometimes with a known fix?
- If you, the TeX expert, were in my shoes, how would you start debugging this to get the previous font/typeface back?

**Update**:  When I use the CLI program `pdffonts` to check the format on a new file, I see the following

```
    % pdffonts booklet.pdf
    name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
    ------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
    DHYUSG+LMRoman12-Regular             Type 1            Custom           yes yes yes     22  0
    GHTMEP+LMRoman12-Bold                Type 1            Custom           yes yes yes     29  0
    FVVOWO+LMMono12-Regular              Type 1            Custom           yes yes yes     30  0
    RPXHHL+LMRomanSlant12-Regular        Type 1            Custom           yes yes yes     35  0
    DHYUSG+LMRoman12-Regular             Type 1            Custom           yes yes yes     40  0
    FVVOWO+LMMono12-Regular              Type 1            Custom           yes yes yes     45  0
```

Comment: if you have the old pdf compare the font lists returned by `pdffonts` or your pdf viewer font menu

Comment: That's a great command to know about @DavidCarlisle, thank you! I'll see if I can dig up some older PDFs and see what's going on, (but unfortunately my primitive build system doesn't keep old copies around, so that image is the one record of this I have)

Comment: I suspect you were using bitmap fonts and now have scalable versions but hard to tell from a picture

Comment: Thank you @DavidCarlisle -- is there a way to check a PDF for whether it's using scalable or bitmap fonts?  And (if you know) would this be something that I control on the pandoc or latex level?  Or is it literally the font file itself that's being used?

Comment: as I say run pdffonts command or use font menu in acrobat and some other readers, type1=scalable type3=bitmap

Comment: If you know when the old PDF file was created, that could provide a valuable clue.  In the new file, the Latin Modern fonts are used, and it's known when those became available.  The old PDF may have been generated with the original Computer Modern (there are slight differences), but the suggestion about bitmap fonts is a good one.

Comment: as barbara said, but latin modern has always been type1 and hasn't changed for decades, a change from cm to lm is a change in your document (or a package you are using) not a change in the tex system

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, funny story, I think this is less a TeX problem and more a MacOS problem.  I normally use MacOS, and print via Preview.  However, I just tried printing the same PDF using Windows and I got what I consider the better looking fonts.  It seems like Preview for MacOS is defaulting to something like Times New Roman (in other words, it can't see the embedded LaTeX fonts).

To sum up some great advice from the comment thread above

- The command line application `pdffonts` can tell you what fonts are used in a PDF
- type 1 fonts are scalable fonts, type 3 are bitmap and may print differently
- A long long time ago computer modern was the default font used, now it's latin modern