# Printing LaTeX Made PDFs in MacOS -- Preview doesn't See Fonts?

Tags: mactex, printing, macos

This is a follow up [to a previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/694421/typefaces-look-off-different-after-an-upgrade).

I use `pandoc` to create PDFs from markdown files, which uses `pdflatex` behind the scenes.  After a bunch of system upgrades, the type in my printed PDFs started to look off.The weight was heavier, and the the kerning was bunched up.

[image]
At first I thought this might be a problem with LaTeX or my MacTex install, but now I believe it's a problem with MacOS.  When I print on MacOS via Preview or Acrobat, I get the font that looks janky.**If I switch to a windows machine** and print there (just via the Edge web browser) the type matches more closely to what I see on the screen and used to see when printing from my Mac.

I now think the "bad" font I see is just good old Times New Roman, being substituted as a default.

Does anyone here know why PDF viewiers/printers on my mac might not see fonts embded in PDFs generated by `pdflatex`?

Comment: The fonts you show in the two images are the same. I'm pretty sure the MacOS does not substitute fonts wholesale. What kind of printer are you printing on? Have you tried printing from Skim (open source Mac previewer).

Comment: That is not Times New Roman.

Comment: And this is Latin Modern, not Times New Roman. The serifs on Times New Roman slant downwards at a slight but noticeable angle, while the serifs in Latin Modern are basically flat.

Comment: When you say the fonts are the same I presume you mean they're the same type face.  I am no font expert so thank you -- that's good information. But (just for clarity because I'm not sure what you're saying) the weight is different, and the kerning is definitely off (I laid them on a light table).  I'm printing on a Brother HL-2170W.  I'll give skim a try, thank you.

Comment: That printer is a PCL6 based printer not Postscript. So this is probably a driver issue for the printer, since the Mac doesn't use PCL6 natively.

Comment: Thank you @AlanMunn, that's a TIL for me.  That's probably it, and I'm happy to accept that as an answer.  

Also, just for completeness, same font kerning and weight different was present when printing from Skim.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Brother HL-2170W printer is a PCL6 based printer, not a Postscript printer. The MacOS doesn't use PCL6 natively, which means that you are quite dependent on the printer driver that Brother supplies for the Mac. This will account for the difference you see when you print from your Windows machine. It's possible the problem can be solved by downloading a new driver for the printer (presumably from Brother), but it's also possible that the supplied driver isn't very good.  For Macs, Postscript printers are much preferred.